# Haskell Printing Strings

Tags: haskell

How do you print Strings in Haskell with newline characters?

```
printString :: String -> String -> String -> String
printString s1 s2 s3 = (s1++"\n"++s2++"\n"++s3)
```

When using the function it prints the entire line including the newline characters as well

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything. It's just a simple function that concatenate strings. How are you printing the value?

Comment: I'm using it in ghci and when using the function it prints the string as all three strings with '\n' in-between, I'm new to Haskell I assumed that was printing

Comment: Well, it's not printing, it's just GHCi _evaluating_ the result. (Then, sure enough, GHCi also prints the result, but that's completely decoupled from your own code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already commented, your code has nothing to do with printing. (It shouldn't have *print* in it's name either!) Printing is a side-effectful action (it makes something appear observably on your screen!) and hence *can't* be done without binding in the `IO` type.

As for the actual task of generating a single three-line string, that is perfectly fulfilled by your suggested solution. `"This\nis\ntest"` *is* a three-line string, as witnessed by

```
Prelude> lines $ printString "This" "is" "test"
["This","is","test"]
```

The reason why GHCi doesn't actually output three separate lines when you just write

```
Prelude> "This\nis\ntest"
"This\nis\ntest"
```

is that the [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) function that's used for this purpose always guarantees a format that's safe to use again in Haskell code, hence it puts strings in quotes and escapes all tricky characters including newlines.

If you simply want to dump a string to the terminal as-is, use `putStrLn` instead of `print`.

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ printString "This" "is" "test"
This
is
test
```

Answer (score 1):

In ghci, you can just type

```
putStrLn "line1\nline2"
```

If you want to write a program to do this, you need to make sure that `putStrLn` runs in the IO monad, for instance, by putting it in main

```
main = do
  <do stuff>
  putStrLn "line1\nline2"
  <do other stuff>
```

Comment: This works but I'm trying to do an Exercise in a book that takes three strings and returns a single string with newlines in between them, is there a way to do that with a function?

Comment: yes but if i type:
printString "This" "is" "test"
into ghci it prints it out as:
This\nis\ntest
When i want it to print as:
This
is
test
with actual newlines rather than characters

Comment: Try `putStrLn (printString s1 s2 s3)`. The ghci REPL will print values as if they were string literals, but execute IO operations like `putStrLn` as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printString` function does not *print* a string, it simply *returns* a string. Because you're running this in GHCi, it gets printed out. But it's GHCi that's printing it; your function itself prints nothing.

If you were to compile some code that calls `printString`, you would discover that nothing gets printed.

By default, GHCi prints stuff as expressions. If you want to write the string to the console unaltered, you need to use `putStrLn`, as the other answers suggest. Compare:

```
Prelude> print "1\n2"
"1\n2"

Prelude> putStrLn "1\n2"
1
2
```

Basically when you write an expression in GHCi, it automatically calls `print` on the result if possible. Because if you're executing something, you probably want to see what the result was. Compiled code doesn't do this; it only prints what you explicitly tell it to.